# JPA update entire entity with all relations

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following Entities:

```java
@Entity
public class MainEntity {

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Id
    @Type(type="uuid-char")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private SubEntity sub;

    private String element;
}

@Entity
public class SubEntity{

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Id
    @Type(type="uuid-char")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    private String element;
}
```

These are coupled together using a `flyway` configuration

Bear in mind that this is only an example, I have multiple more Entities which are connected to MainEntity via `@OneToOne` or `@OneToMany`, all using `@CascadeType.ALL`

And I want to update an existing entity - using the MainEntity ID and a new MainEntity Object. For this I have a JpaRepository with a custom @Query

```java
@Repository
public interface SalesOpportunityRepository extends JpaRepository<MainEntity, UUID> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update MainEntity oldEntity set oldEntity = :updatedEntity where oldEntity.id = :id")
    void updateEntity(@Param("id") UUID id, @Param("updatedEntity") MainEntity updatedEntity);
}
```

But running this, using either a h2 db locally, or a postgres db in test env. I get this error:

`org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:`

I see many struggle with this, but everytime `CascadeType.All` is proposed, but as I already have it - this will not help.

Not sure if the update sql for updating the entire entity might be the problem her

Comment: What is wrong with just calling `save`? Why do you think you need a query for this?

Comment: Looking at your mapping I am wondering how your `MainEntity` knows how to connect to the `SubEntity`. AFAIK there should be a `@JoinColumn`

Comment: @M.Deinum Then I have to get, and then save - which is two calls and not very efficient.
If there is not possible to call save on an existing entity I am not aware of?

Comment: Yes, I did not include the `flyway` configuration which couples these tables together @XtremeBaumer

There is defined a SubEntityId in the MainEntity DB table because of this configuration

Comment: You should make the example at least complete in as not missing crucial configuration parts. You could attempt to `merge()` the entity

Comment: You are attempting to bypass save by giving a JPQL query the entity and expecting it to abide by your mappings and figure out what to update. This isn't possible with JPA bulk update queries but is if you want to break out the non-JPA api. (Eclipselink has updateObject calls which do what you want, and I'm sure Hibernate will have equivalent api). Otherwise, you have to form your update query and set each property individually in it, just as you might for an SQL update statement.

Comment: Aha, ok then it was probably more troublesome than I imagined - I think I will go for the approach of fetching - then saving instead. Thank you for your answers.